# Custom tab in Sales order Shipment page

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order

Hi I want to add Custom tab in Sales order Shipment page in Backend. So which Block i need to override

I added in Sales Order View page in below code

```
<blocks>
      <delivery>
        <class>MPS_Delivery_Block</class>
      </delivery>
    <adminhtml>
        <rewrite>
            <sales_order_view_info>MPS_Delivery_Block_Sales_Order_View_Info</sales_order_view_info>
        </rewrite>
    </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
```

Can you please tell me which class i need to override to add custom tab in sales order shipement page

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_shipment_new>
      <reference name="content">
          <action method="setTemplate"><template>delivery/sales/order/shipment/create/items.phtml</template></action>
      </reference>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_shipment_new>
```

I got this error **`Fatal error: Call to a member function setData() on boolean in : app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Form\Container.php on line 129`** when i click **`ship`**  button in order details page

Comment: Can you add more details, if possible with screenshot, exactly which part you want to override?

Comment: Whenever we click shipment button it will redirect to shipment page there i want to add custom tab

Comment: You mean when we click on "Ship" button on order page?

Comment: Yes correct ....

Comment: Do you want to add new section or want to override Items section on new shipment page? Because with your code, it will override new shipment form and won't add anything new to it.

Comment: I wan to override that template

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code in your config file

```
<blocks>
  <delivery>
    <class>MPS_Delivery_Block</class>
  </delivery>
    <adminhtml>
        <rewrite>
            <sales_order_shipment_create_form>MPS_Delivery_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Shipment_Create_Form</sales_order_shipment_create_form>
        </rewrite>
    </adminhtml>
</blocks>
```

Comment: ok can you please tell me the referncename

Comment: Reference name? sorry but I think I didnt get you there

Comment: in layout.xml we need add right

Comment: I got this error after adding this Fatal error: Call to a member function setData() on boolean in \app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Form\Container.php on line 129

Comment: Check my updated question